# Bash: How to run command expecting quotes using a variable?

Tags: git, bash

I have a git command that I would like to run in my script:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "STUFF HERE IN QUOTES"
```

The thing is, in my script I am dynamically creating the string that is represented by `STUFF HERE IN QUOTES`:

```
ENVFILTER=""
while read commit; do
    IFS="|" read date hash message <<< "$commit"
    DATE_NO_SPACE="$(echo "${date}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"
    COMMIT_ENV=$(cat <<-END
         if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = $hash ]
         then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$DATE_NO_SPACE"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$DATE_NO_SPACE"
         fi
    END
    )
    ENVFILTER="$ENVFILTER$COMMIT_ENV"
done < $tmpfile
git filter-branch -f --env-filter \'"$ENVFILTER"\' // <---------- does not work
```

Basically I start with an empty string `ENVFILTER` and I concat it with other strings to form a bunch of if statements. I'm having trouble with the last step, which is running the actual command. I don't know how to run it with the expected quotes + the interpolated value.

=== UPDATE ===

After looking at @chepner's answer and using `"$ENVFILTER"`, I can now successfully run the command. So is answer is correct.

However, there is an error about my `if` statements (not related to the quotes):

```
Rewrite eeb8860c13179c931a513a9ada76dc109324d790 (1/17)/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.6.2/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 313: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.6.2/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 313: `     fi     if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  08a2d85f9412c67435929d80ccc5b914f3ad8547  ]'
env filter failed:      if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  59d13c174c34b6540f61585ef507abcef29ab22e  ]
     then
 export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-10-02T21:16:37-04:00"
 export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-10-02T21:16:37-04:00"
     fi     if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  08a2d85f9412c67435929d80ccc5b914f3ad8547  ]
     then
 export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-08-31T17:54:28-04:00"
 export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-08-31T17:54:28-04:00"
     fi     if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  d7801396f5fb1092beec3aa484361cd50ab35e9e  ]
     then
 export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-08-31T17:53:07-04:00"
 export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-08-31T17:53:07-04:00"
     fi     if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  7930e9be149a57229c9fc26ccffe1c6453317d70  ]
     then
 export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-08-31T17:48:03-04:00"
 export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-08-31T17:48:03-04:00"
     fi     if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  f0849b2de99ac37790eaf6e40c8980988e865c7c  ]
     then
 export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-08-31T17:46:33-04:00"
 export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-08-31T17:46:33-04:00"
     fi
[
```

Is there something wrong with it? I don't get it

Comment: The command *doesn't* actually expect literal quotes. When documentation shows quotes, those are *syntactic* quotes, indicating *to the shell*, not to `git`, that content should be passed as a single argument; that argument passed by the shell on the `argv` array includes only literal content - syntax is removed during the shell's processing.

Comment: Looks like maybe you didn't put the `;` inside of the quotes the way chepner did in the answer?

Comment: ooo is that required? so like this `if ...; then ...; fi;`

Comment: that did it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! you guys are the best!!

Comment: BTW, this is safe-ish to the extent that you can trust the value of `$hash` to be constrained, but the approach you're taking could be subject to shell-injection vulnerabilities if handling untrusted or arbitrary data; I certainly would do things differently if it were, say, the message rather than the hash that you were operating on. Programmatically generating code that'll later be `eval`'d is generally something to be done only with substantial care and caution, or better avoided altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `ENVFILTER` contains the correct code, this is all you need:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$ENVFILTER"
```

Any special characters in the *value* of `ENVFILTER` are passed as-is to `git` as long as the expansion is quoted.

---

That said, I would clean up the generator a little:

```
envfilter=
while IFS="|" read -r date hash message; do
    envfilter+="if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = \"$hash\" ]; then echo \"here\"; fi;"
done < "$tmpfile"
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$envfilter"
```

Comment: I'd clean it up a fair bit more than that -- there's no need to do code generation here; we could refer back to an environment variable for contents to match against.

Comment: oooo cool! i'm going to update my answer to show the actual code in my script. it's complaining about my if statements. one second

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming the space before the `"|"` is in error?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is as far as I would want to go without seeing the actual code (which appears to be forthcoming).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, muscle memory put that there :)

Comment: you guys are the best!! adding the `;` fixed it

Comment: @Edmund The problem there was that `cat` treats `\n` as a literal, two-character string, not a single newline character. Since you aren't actually looking at the generated code, it's simpler to give `bash` a long, `;`-delimited string of commands rather than a "nice" looking newline-delimited string.

Comment: In the updated code (which I should have looked for before my previous comment), the trailing newline that the here document provides is stripped by the command substitution. Either way, using a semicolon is simpler than trying to shove a newline in there :)